# The best way to add an extra attribute to checkout shipping form fields

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, knockoutjs

I want to know the best way to add some extra attributes ('disabled' & 'readonly') in shipping checkout form.

I found some workaround to bind a `js` in `knockout` but my js is loaded before the form !

> web/template/shipping-address/form.html

```
<form class="form form-shipping-address 22" id="co-shipping-form"
      data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')},
                afterRender: function(){ //My js bind here
                    jQuery('input[name=postcode]').prop('readonly', true);
                    jQuery('input[name=postcode]').prop('disabled', true);
                    alert('ok');
                }">
...
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Comment: @Haritha the field already exists, I just want to add the two properties

Comment: @Ben Crook  I know you can give me a trick about this

Comment: Try these bindings,

<input name="postcode" type='text' data-bind="disable: true" />
<input name="postcode" type='text' data-bind="readonly: true" />

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html

Comment: I can't bind it like, take a look in web/template/shipping-address/form.html I should bind it in form like my exemple